# How to get YouTubeBaseActivity using YouTube API in Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-youtube-api

I've tried to play youtube video on android  with YouTubePlayerSupportFragment.

But in my case, I have to overlay play button on top of youtube player so Ive decided to use YouTubeBaseActivity.

My class is  extending BaseFragment  (Fragment) which means I can't extends YouTubeBaseActivity. ( can't extends 2 sigh...)

1. Is there any method to get YouTubeBaseActivity without extending it?
2. or can I get YouTubePlayerView like I've done with YouTubePlayerSupportFragment ( as below).
3. If its not possible then can I display play button only on the player?? 
   (Chromeless style doesn't show the play button)

```java
public class StudentFragment extends BaseFragment{

...

public View onCreateView{

fragment1 = (YouTubeFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_youtube);

fragment1.setVideoId(movie_Id);

}




public class YouTubeFragment extends YouTubePlayerSupportFragment implements YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener{

public void setVideoId(final String videoId) {

mVideoId = videoId;

initialize(youtube_developer_key, this);

}
```

etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've tried to play youtube video on android with
>   YouTubePlayerSupportFragment.
>
> But in my case, I have to overlay play button on top of youtube player
>   so Ive decided to use YouTubeBaseActivity.

It does not make any difference. You will experience the same behavior using the Activity and/or the Fragment.

> My class is extending BaseFragment (Fragment) which means I can't
>   extends YouTubeBaseActivity. ( can't extends 2 sigh...)

Even if it was possible, it would not make any sense to have a single class that extends both an Activity and a Fragment.

> Is there any method to get YouTubeBaseActivity without extending it?
>
> or can I get YouTubePlayerView like I've done with
>   YouTubePlayerSupportFragment ( as below).

You have two simple options: either use the `YouTubeBaseActivity` + `YouTubePlayerView`, or go with the `YouTubeSupportFragment`.

> If its not possible then can I display play button only on the
>   player?? (Chromeless style doesn't show the play button)

And now we get to the point: **you cannot place any `View` over the YouTube player**, otherwise video playback will keep stopping every second or so.

You can try using the `STANDARD` style for the `YouTubePlayer` instance (which, if I am not mistaken, already shows a button over the video) and see if that suits your needs.

Comment: thx ! how about the popup window? can i place it on top of the youtube player?